# How to understand the second 'that although their analyses ...' clause?

Tags: meaning

From Don Lee Fred Nilsen.(1972). English Adverbials. p.17.

> Calling ***to him*** a word-group, functioning as 'prepositional
> object' illustrates one common weakness of the traditional grammarians
> in dealing with two-word verbs; they feel so strongly that such a word
> as ***to*** is a preposition (literally), that although their analyses
> would logically lead them to the point of saying that words in such
> constructions are co-occurring with the  preceding verb, and are
> therefore 'postpositions',it seems that they cannot force themselves
> to analyze the constructions in this way.

How to interpret 'that although...analyze the constructions in this way.'?

It is not proper to say 'they feel so strongly that although...analyze the constructions in this way.' And also,it is not the attributive clause of 'a preposition'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

> His mom feels so strongly
>
> that he should eat all of the vegetables on his plate,
>
> that she won't give him any ice cream until he does so.

The first *that*-clause expresses what she feels so strongly about. The second *that*-clause expresses the consequence of her feeling so strongly about it.

She feels so strongly that ( X should happen) that (she does Y).
**so** there expresses degree or extent or intensity and the second clause expesses a consequence that reflects the degree of intensity of her feeling; it is a complement of **so**.

In the original, there is an *interruption* between the feeling strongly about something and the consequence, beginning with **although**:

> His mom feels so strongly
>
> that he should eat all of the vegetables on his plate,
>
> that
>
> *although she is ususally very nice to him and so you might think she would always give him as much ice cream as he wanted, it seems*
>
> she won't give him any ice cream until he does so.

The interruption expresses an expectation that might well arise from her usual behavior, and **although** sets up a "contrary to expectations" situation.

To apply this to the original: contrary to expectations, their analyses of such constructions in which the preposition occurs *after* the verb does not logically lead them to conclude that the little word is actually a "postposition".

P.S. The construction "feels so strongly" can be followed by a prepositional phrase which presents the topic of strong feelings, which in turn is followed by a *that*-clause:

> His mom feels so strongly *about the catastrophic effects of climate change* [that she is putting all the ice-cream money
> in the bank, saving up to buy an electric car.]

Comment: Good answer to be accepted.

Answer (score -1):

The meaning is *if they wanted to apply their analysis consistently, they would say *X*, but they cannot force themselves to say that, so instead they analyze inconsistently.*